# Show inequality holds

Tags: inequality

Let $z \geq y \geq 1$. Show that

$$
\sqrt{\frac{y}{1+z}} + \sqrt{\frac{z}{1+y}} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{y+z}} > 2
$$

These are actually the last steps of a bigger inequality, but I can't think of a nice way to prove it (no differentiation please).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalently, we may prove the inequality
$$ \sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}\geq 2 \tag{1}$$
under the constraints $x,y,z\geq 0$ and $x+y+z=1$. That follows from:
$$ \forall x\in(0,1),\quad \sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}\geq 2x \tag{2}$$
that is equivalent to:
$$ \forall x\in(0,1),\quad 4x(1-x)\leq 1 \tag{3} $$
that is a straightforward consequence of the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Thank you. I had obviously not chosen the right constraint by setting $x = 1$.